# Form submission unidentified index

Tags: php, html, forms, submit

I am trying to submit a form on the same page and I get this error:

> Undefined index: text1

And:

> Undefined index: text2.

Here is to code I am using:

```
<?php include('includes/header.php') ?>
<section class="login">
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submitbtn'])) {
        $text1 = $_POST['text1'];
        $text2 = $_POST['text2'];
        echo "Success! You entered: " . $text1 . "<br>";
        echo "Success! You entered: " . $text2 . "<br>";
    } else {
        ?>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <p><label>Text1:</label><input type="text" name"text1"/></p>
            <p><label>Text2:</label><input type="text" name"text2"/></p>
            <input type="submit" name="submitbtn"/>
        </form>

    <?php } ?>
</section>
<?php include('includes/footer.php') ?>
```

- header.php consists of an html navigation and it opens a connection to
  the database.
- footer.php has the footer and closes the connection.

What am I doing wrong? Also is there a better way in submitting a form on the same page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget  `=` in `name"text1"`. It would be

```
 <p><label>Text1:</label><input type="text" name="text1"/></p>
 <p><label>Text2:</label><input type="text" name="text2"/></p>
```